# Plotly plot is pushed out of bounds in flexdashboard

Tags: r, plotly, r-markdown, r-plotly, flexdashboard

I am having trouble getting my plotly plot to fit in its flexdashboard container. The bottom gets cut off.

Consider the following reprex:

````
---
title: "Plotly Flexdashboard Conflict"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
      source_code: embed

---

Column
---

### In this tab, the plot is pushed out of bonds by the selectize items.

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(gapminder)
library(flexdashboard)

gapminder_highlighted <- 
  highlight_key(gapminder[1:408,], ~country, "Select a country")

gapminder_ggplot <- 
  gapminder_highlighted %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = lifeExp, group = country), alpha = 0.2) + 
  geom_line()
  
gapminder_plotly <- ggplotly(gapminder_ggplot)

highlight(gapminder_plotly, dynamic = T, selectize = T, persistent = T)
 
```
 
### Without selectize, all is well. The x axis is visible.

```{r}
gapminder_plotly
```

Column
---

### When plots overflow, flexdashboard is meant to add a scrollbar. E.g.

```{r}
plot(cars)
plot(nhtemp)
plot(cars)
plot(nhtemp)
```

### Although this does not actually work for all elements. E.g. Text generated from code chunks fails to trigger slider addition: 

```{r}
cat( rep("Flex is not responsive to text overflow here.           ", 100) )
print("This line is hidden")
```
````

Output is on Rpubs here so you can have a look: https://rpubs.com/kenwosu/661556

The first gapminder plot is pushed out of bounds by the selectize items. And flexdashboard doesn't trigger the addition of a vertical scrollbar like it should.

[image: plotly overflow when selectize elements added]

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Does this look a little bit better? I changed the y axis to start at 0 and it appears to be a little bit more clearly displayed. I just added `+ expand_limits(y = 0)` to the end of the ggplot graph. I tried messing with *ggplotly()* but it appeared it was the ggplot graphic that had the figure issue.

````
---
title: "Plotly Flexdashboard Conflict"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
      source_code: embed

---

Column
---

### In this tab, the plot is pushed out of bonds by the selectize items.

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(gapminder)
library(flexdashboard)

gapminder_highlighted <- 
  highlight_key(gapminder[1:408,], ~country, "Select a country")

gapminder_ggplot <- 
  gapminder_highlighted %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = lifeExp, group = country), alpha = 0.2) + 
  geom_line() + expand_limits(y = 0)
  
gapminder_plotly <- ggplotly(gapminder_ggplot)

highlight(gapminder_plotly, dynamic = T, selectize = T, persistent = T)
 
```
 
### Without selectize, all is well. The x axis is visible.

```{r}
gapminder_plotly
```

Column
---

### When plots overflow, flexdashboard is meant to add a scrollbar. E.g.

```{r}
plot(cars)
plot(nhtemp)
plot(cars)
plot(nhtemp)
```

### Although this does not actually work for all elements. E.g. Text generated from code chunks fails to trigger slider addition: 

```{r}
cat( rep("Flex is not responsive to text overflow here.           ", 100) )
print("This line is hidden")
```
````

Comment: This ALMOST does the trick! But if screen size is shrunk significantly (as, for example, on mobile display), then the bottom gets hidden again. It seems the ultimate solution would need to come from the flexdashboard or plotly package developers.